# Recebimento de dados via conexão serial C#

Tags: c#, conexão, serial

Preciso fazer um programa que tem que enviar um comando para um rádio conectado via porta serial e este retorna seu ID. A conexão com a porta e o envio de dados está ok, quando envio alguma coisa a luz pisca. Porém preciso do seu retorno e pelo que vi no debug o programa não entra na classe serialPort1_DataReceived. O que poderia ser?

Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;  // necessário para ter acesso as portas     


namespace serialteste
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string RxString;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void atualizaListaCOMs()
    {
        int i;
        bool quantDiferente;    //flag para sinalizar que a quantidade de portas mudou

        i = 0;
        quantDiferente = false;

        //se a quantidade de portas mudou
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count == SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length)
        {
            foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                if (comboBox1.Items[i++].Equals(s) == false)
                {
                    quantDiferente = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            quantDiferente = true;
        }

        //Se não foi detectado diferença
        if (quantDiferente == false)
        {
            return;                     //retorna
        }

        //limpa comboBox
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        //adiciona todas as COM diponíveis na lista
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
        //seleciona a primeira posição da lista
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //atualizaListaCOMs();

    }





    private void btConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
        {
            try
            {


                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                serialPort1.Open();

            }
            catch
            {
                return;

            }
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                btConectar.Text = "Desconectar";
                comboBox1.Enabled = false;

            }
        }
        else
        {

            try
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                btConectar.Text = "Conectar";
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)  // se porta aberta
            serialPort1.Close();            //fecha a porta


    }

    private void btEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)          //porta está aberta
            serialPort1.Write(textBoxEnviar.Text);  //envia o texto presente no textbox
    }

    private void trataDadoRecebido(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxReceber.AppendText(RxString);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {


        textBoxReceber.Text="alguma coisa recebeu";
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();              //le o dado disponível na serial
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebido));   //chama outra thread para escrever o dado no text box
    }

    private void Atualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        atualizaListaCOMs();
    }      


}
}
```

Comment: Deve está faltando alto relacionado a  `serialPort1_DataReceived`, algum `delegate` por exemplo para disparar este procedimento. Verifique isto na documentação, SKD. @kaamis

Comment: @HStackOverflow dei uma pesquisada mas nao entendi muito bem. Poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer essa relaçao? Pesquisei sobre delegates mas nao consegui inserir no projeto acima!

Comment: Você tem algum tipo de documentação (SDK) da comunicação com este equipamento? Caso tenha deixe o link aqui, eu posso verificar para tentar uma solução. @kaamis

Comment: Ve se esse artigo do CodeProject te ajuda http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners

Comment: Interrupções de recebimento de dados pela porta serial as vezes não funcionou comigo, problema mais frequente no Mono C#. Eu recomendo o utilização desse Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SerialPortLib . Para instruções de uso e exemplos: https://github.com/genielabs/serialport-lib-dotnet .

Answer (score 1):

Para Disparar o processo seria:

```
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RecebeDadosSerial);
```

Porem seria interessante nos enviar um manual de sobre seu dispositivo. Pode ser que não esteja enviando nada para sua serial.
Pode ser que precisa ser enviado o comando ENQ para ter retorno, pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
string ENQ = "\u0005\r\n"; // -> \n padrão de Escape 
        _serialPort.Write(ENQ);
```

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pela ajuda, o problema era o comando que estava sendo enviado e/ou a velocidade do rádio (componente conectado via serial). O led piscava mas não voltava com a resposta, agora está tudo ok!